# Java 2D arrays, unable to find a way to store double calculation as an element

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having an issue with an assignment in `Java`. I'm using NetBeans.

I'm trying to input some calculations into a 2D array so that when the user inputs a value it will automatically get stored and at the end print out the result. I'm getting an error and it wont let me do this and cant understand or find a way to fix this.

I'm getting "double cannot be converted to int", but I'm not actually wanting to convert to int, this makes me think that I cant store a double into an `array` with this code. Can you please suggest something?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        //prestamo interes del 18% al tiempo que se solicite
        
        double interes, numerador, denominador;
        int periodo = 0;
        double cuota[];
        double cantPrestamo[];
        
        periodo = periodo*12;
        interes = .18/12;
        
       
        String[]empleados = {"Jose Rivera", "Maria Zuniga", "Francisco Sanchez"};
        
        System.out.print("Introduzca el monto del prestamo: ");
        cantPrestamo = leer.nextDouble();
        
        System.out.print("Introduzca la cantidad en meses: ");
        periodo = leer.nextInt();
        
        numerador = interes * Math.pow(1 + interes, periodo);
        denominador = Math.pow(1 + interes, periodo)-1;
        cuota = cantPrestamo * (numerador / denominador);
        
        //System.out.printf("La cuota a pagar Lps.%.2f", cuota);
        //System.out.println();
        
        
       double[][] cuotaPeriodo;
       cuotaPeriodo = new double [cuota][cantPrestamo];
         
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `cuota = cantPrestamo * (numerador / denominador);` doesn't compile because you're trying to multiply a `double[]` by a `double`. Then this line: `cuotaPeriodo = new double[cuota][cantPrestamo];` doesnt' work because cuotaPeriodo is of type `double[][]` meaning a 2D array of `double` and you're trying to use `double[]` as the size parameters of the new 2D array instead of integers. It might help you to look at the [Java Tutorial on Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

In:

```
cuotaPeriodo = new double [cuota][cantPrestamo];
```

You are initializing the array, not putting content in it. You must create the array object either specifying the capacity with:

```
cuotaPeriodo= new double [9][8]; //an array with 9 rows and 8 columns
cuotaPeriodo[0][1]=0.1;//set value in row 0 and column 1
```

or putting the content that you want in it:

```
cuotaPeriodo={{0.0,0.1,0.2},{1.0,1.1,1.2}}; // 2 rows, 3 columns
```